# Check if date in one dataframe is between two dates in another dataframe, by group

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have the following problem. I've got a dataframe with start and end dates for each group. There might be **more than one start and end date per group**, like this:

```
group   start_date    end_date
 1      2020-01-03    2020-03-03
 1      2020-05-03    2020-06-03
 2      2020-02-03    2020-06-03
```

And another dataframe with one row per date, per group, like this:

```
group   date
 1     2020-01-03
 1     2020-02-03
 1     2020-03-03
 1     2020-04-03
 1     2020-05-03
 1     2020-06-03
 2     2020-02-03
 3     2020-03-03
 4     2020-04-03
      .
      .
```

So I want to create a column `is_between` in an efficient way, ideally avoiding loops, so I get the following dataframe

```
group   date          is_between
 1     2020-01-03        1
 1     2020-02-03        1
 1     2020-03-03        1
 1     2020-04-03        0
 1     2020-05-03        1
 1     2020-06-03        1
 2     2020-02-03        1
 3     2020-03-03        1
 4     2020-04-03        1
      .
      .
```

So it gets a 1 when a group's date is between the dates in the first dataframe. I'm guessing some combination of `groupby`, `where`, `between` and maybe `map` might do it, but I'm not finding the correct one. Any ideas?

Comment: How many rows do your dataframes have?

Comment: merge and do the condition ?

Comment: the first one about 70-80 (gets updated every day), the second one, a couple thousands. This has to run on a 512mb RAM virtual machine, along many other processes so efficiency is quite important

Comment: Merge would bring duplicates for groups that get more than one starting and ending date, which would mean then having to sort by group and `is_between` and then drop_duplicates, which doesn't seem too efficient, but it would work and it's better than what I've currently got.

Comment: For `80 x 10k` data, merge isn't too bad. And it's fast.

Comment: I'l check how it does performance-wise

Comment: @QuangHoang @ YOBEN_S only merge and filtering will not work here I think. You need to check later on which dates have been filtered to create the new column

Comment: Went from 3.6 seconds to 0.025 in my machine so it's an improvement. I think it's enough for my purposes, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Based on @YOBEN_S and @Quang Hoang's advice this made it:

```
df = df.merge(dic_dates, how='left')
df['is_between'] = np.where(df.date.between(pd.to_datetime(df.start_date),
                                                                   pd.to_datetime(df.end_Date)),1, 0)
df = (df.sort_values(by=['group', 'date', 'is_between'])
            .drop_duplicates(subset=['group', 'date'], keep='last'))
```

Comment: Hi Juan. I've just encountered a similar problem. Could you please tell what is df, and what's dic_dates in your example>

Answer (score 1):

you could try with `merge_asof`, `by` the group and `on` the date and start_date, then check where the date is less than end_date and finally assign back to the original df2

```
ser = (pd.merge_asof(df2.reset_index() #for later index alignment
                        .sort_values('date'), 
                     df1.sort_values('start_date'), 
                     by='group', 
                     left_on='date', right_on='start_date', 
                     direction='backward')
         .assign(is_between=lambda x: x.date<=x.end_date)
         .set_index(['index'])['is_between']
        )

df2['is_between'] = ser.astype(int)

print (df2)
   group       date  is_between
0      1 2020-01-03           1
1      1 2020-02-03           1
2      1 2020-03-03           1
3      1 2020-04-03           0
4      1 2020-05-03           1
5      1 2020-06-03           1
6      2 2020-02-03           1
7      3 2020-03-03           0
8      4 2020-04-03           0
```